# Knowledge Base - Article Type as seperate tab

Tags: knowledge, articles

I'd like to organize content like FAQ and Training Articles so I created two article types like FAQ and Training.
Is it Possible to place them in different tabs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only Way this could be possible is create a visualforce and then use as a Visualforce Tab

Here is the sample code to get started

```
<apex:page >
  <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
 <ul>
 <knowledge:articleList  articleVar="article" articleTypes="FAQ__kav"> 
 <li><a href="{!URLFOR($Action.KnowledgeArticle.View, article.id)}">{!article.title}</a>
  </li>
 </knowledge:articleList>
</ul>
   </apex:outputPanel>
 </apex:page>
```

> The key is articleTypes variable and that will filter based on article types .